# Can't create table in database using class model in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I'm using node.js with express and sequelize and my DB is mysql.
I tried to create a class model as written in the documentation: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html. I was able to connect to the DB, but couldn't figure out how to sync the model with the DB in order to create tables. here is my user model:

```
const { DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
const connection = require("../server");

export class User extends Model { }

User.init({
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    userType: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    }
}, {
    connection
});
```

and here is my server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

const app = express();
const port = 8080;

const connection = new Sequelize("coupons2", "root", "1234", {
    host: "localhost",
    dialect: "mysql"
})

connection.sync()
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Connection to DB was successful");
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error("Unable to connect to DB", err);
    });

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
})

module.exports = connection;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I managed to create tables by importing the models to my server.js:
`const models = require("./src/models/index");`, and using the sync() method.

Comment: @Arya answered early. So, that should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think you forgot to require the `Sequelize` as shown in document you mentioned above

```
`const {Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
```

and if you want that it table create automatically by models you can use `sequelize.sync` in your project

```
await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
console.log("All models were synchronized successfully.");
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I tried adding the 2 code sections and it didn't work

Comment: check out this https://github.com/Arya4514/Node_Shop repositories model directory maybe it could help something.

Answer (score 1):

- `User.sync()` - creates the table if it doesn't exist (and does nothing if it already exists)
- `User.sync({ force: true })` - creates the table, dropping it first if it already existed
- `User.sync({ alter: true })` - checks what is the current state of the table in the database (which columns it has, what are their data types, etc), and then performs the necessary changes in the table to make it match the model.

```
(async () => {
    await sequelize.sync({ alter: true });
})();
```